# Autocompletebox doesn't show the list of contents as suggestion while binding from a sqlite db

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, autocomplete

I have to get the suggestion list in the autocomplete textbox.I give the input as binding names..You can see in the xaml code in the listbox i can bind the names from Img source..but in the autocomplete i cant.. guide me that should i have to insert any code for this in Mainpage.cs

```
            <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>

    <Button Content="Button" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />

        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Img}" Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding}">


        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>







                    <DataTemplate>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                    <Image Height="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,-400,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" Source="{Binding thumb}"/>
                    <!--ContentControl Width="150" Height="110" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,-400,0" Content="{Binding Image}"/>-->
                    <TextBlock  TextWrapping="NoWrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="190,-167,-200,0" Text="{Binding title}"/>
                    <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="190,-135,-200,0" Text="{Binding page}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="190,-95,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />




                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>

    <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="157,6,0,0" Name="textBox1" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" />
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="261,6,0,0" Name="autoCompleteBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="182"  ItemsSource="{Binding Img}" ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel >
                    <TextBlock 

                Text="{Binding Name}"/>


                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, I changed the xaml as

```
        </TextBox>

        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" FilterMode="Contains" Margin="-11,-14,0,0" Name="autoCompleteBox1" ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800" Background="White" Height="91" Text="" TextChanged="autocompletebox1_Textchanged" BorderBrush="White" Visibility="Visible" Padding="50,14,6,4" BorderThickness="0" IsHitTestVisible="True">
            <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="25,25,0,0" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Image Height="110" Width="150" Source="{Binding Image1}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: the code behind ? .. did you sett the itemSource to a list or a class ?